# Can the Community user correct the grammar?

Tags: support

I have noticed that [the Community user edited a post](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity) to correct the grammar.
Is that possible, or was that done by a real person?

Comment: I’d guess (pure speculation) that it’s a person — that Jeff Atwood or the moderators or something can get edits attributed to @Community.  Or possibly that edits suggested by anonymous users and later accepted end up getting owned by @Community?

Comment: On the other hand, if it’s any kind of automated grammar-bot, I’d be very concerned: it’s extremely important on this site that questions and answers should be able to include examples of bad grammar!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edits attributed to the Community user are suggested edits made by non-registered users. You can see this in the [edit-suggestion post](https://english.stackexchange.com/edit-suggestions/57).

Comment: waiwai, that link shows (Sept 2012) "Page Not Found".  What did it say?